# About a well-defined homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $G_1$, $G_2$ are groups and $N_1 \subset G_1$, $N_2 \subset G_2$ are normal subgroups. Let $f:G_1\to G_2$ be a homomorphism. When is $\bar{f}(N_1 g) = N_2 f(g)$ a well-defined homomorphism from $G_1/N_1$ to $G_2/N_2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't necessarily well-defined. A necessary condition is that, for $g\in N_1$, $N_2f(g)=N_2$, that is, $f(g)\in N_2$. In other words, we need that $f(N_1)\subset N_2$.

This condition is also sufficient, because in this case
$$
N_1\subset\ker \pi\circ f
$$
where $\pi\colon G_2\to G_2/N_2$ is the canonical projection.

A general result is the following: if $\varphi\colon G\to G'$ is a group homomorphism and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $N\subset\ker\varphi$, then
$$
Ng\mapsto \varphi(g)
$$
is a well defined group homomorphism $G/N\to G'$. It is well defined because, if $Ng_1=Ng_2$, then $g_1g_2^{-1}\in N$, so $g_1g_2^{-1}\in \ker\varphi$ and therefore $\varphi(g_1)=\varphi(g_2)$. It is a homomorphism in an obvious way.

---

A counterexample to the general assertion is easy to make. Consider the identity $1_{\mathbb{Z}}\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$; let $N_2=\{0\}$ and $N_1=2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I understand it now :)